# Complements being open or closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

It is well known in topology that, when we say that a set is "open," we really mean that a given set is an element of our topology. Another important thing to consider is that a set is closed iff its complement is open. So consider the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$. That is, consider the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by arbitrary unions of the open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider any set $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Since $(a,b)$ is defined in our topology, by definition, $(a,b)$ is open. When sets are open, their complements must be closed. So let's consider $(a,b)^c$:

$$(a,b)^c= (-\infty, a] \cup [b,\infty)$$

But this looks funny to me. Is $(\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$ closed? After all, we have open braces around the $\pm \infty$'s.

If we assumed the metric space understanding of $\mathbb{R}'s$ open and closed sets, could we reasonably assume that $(\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)$ is closed? Because, if you look at it, $(\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$ contains all of its accumulation points (even approaching the  $\pm$ infinites).

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my post. My question is: Is $(a,b)^c$ closed? And if so, why?

Comment: Infinities are not accumulation points because they are not points. Not in the real line at least (but there's a way to add $\pm\infty$ to the real line an give a metric that restricted to $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to the euclidean metric, the resulting space is isomorphic to $[0,1]$)

Comment: As you said, because it is the complement of an open set. No more, no less.

Comment: @Alessandro I don't mean to treat $\infty$ as a number. I'm merely attempting to say that every accumulation point $x$ in the positive and negative direction is in the set when $x \leq a$ or $x \geq b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open and closed are not mutually exclusive. As you mentioned, $(a,b)$ is open by definition of the topology, and $(a,b)^c$ is closed by definition of closed (i.e. the complement is open). $(a,b)^c=(-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)$ is not open because any neighborhood around the points $a$ or $b$ will always include points outside of $(a,b)^c$, i.e. there is no open ball around $a$ or $b$ that's contained inside the set. Your remark about accumulation points provides yet another way to see that it is closed: $(a,b)^c$ contains all it's accumulation points.